# No value accessor for form control

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, form-control

I'm using Angular2-rc5, and I'm currently getting an error on my login page. I'm trying to make a form but the console throws exceptions telling me that it can't find my `formcontroll`s even though I create it on init. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

**login component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
    
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    providers: [LoginService],
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    private loginForm: FormGroup; // our model driven form
    private submitted: boolean; // keep track on whether form is submitted
    private events: any[] = []; // use later to display form changes
    
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private ls:LoginService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl('',[<any>Validators.required]),
            password: new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(6)]),
            rememberMe: new FormControl()
        });
    }
    save(model: User, isValid: boolean) {
        console.log("Test");
        console.log(model, isValid);
    }
    // Login in user
    login(email: any, password: any){
        this.ls.login(email, password, false); 
    }
}
```

**Page.html**

```html
<div id="login-page">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <form class="login-form" [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(loginForm.value, loginForm.valid)">
            <div >
                <div class="input-field col s12 center">
                    <p class="center login-form-text">Login page</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="email" type="email"> 
                    <label class="center-align" for="email" formControlName="email">Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="password" type="password"> 
                    <label class="center" for="password" formControlName="password">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12 login-text">
                    <input id="remember-me" type="checkbox" formControlName="rememberMe">
                    <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <ahref="index.html">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                <div >
                    <p><a href="page-register.html">Register Now!</a></p>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <p><a href="page-forgot-password.html">Forgot password ?</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Exception**

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./LoginComponent
> class LoginComponent - inline template:13:45 caused by: No value
> accessor for form control with name: 'email'.....

Comment: In my case, I had given incorrect name of component. Ex. <p-multiselect... instead of <p-multiSelect...

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You are adding the `formControlName` to the label and not the input.

You have this:

```
<div >
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="email" type="email"> 
    <label class="center-align" for="email" formControlName="email">Email</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try using this:

```
<div >
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="email" type="email" formControlName="email"> 
    <label class="center-align" for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update the other input fields as well.

Comment: The same issue to me because I applied formControlName for a span tag. Thank you!

Comment: I even had this issue with a custom component that had a `@Input formControl`. In one place the formControl was correctly passed to my component in another one the above error occurred. I ended up renaming the formControl input to something distinct.

Without this answer I would've never found this :/

Comment: A thumbs up from me too for this solution - I'm using a `<mat-form-field>` element and had the `formControlName` applied to that (didn't work). Moving it to the contained `<mat-select>` element resolved the issue perfectly!

Comment: I was using ngModel in the option tag, so I moved it to the select tag and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue (in a test and the actual component separate times) because I was using a form control name on a custom element and I forgot to import the module for that element, which prevented form control from proper binding.

Comment: How to apply this solution in case of **Material Checkbox**?

Answer (score 88):

**For UnitTest angular 2 with angular material** you have to add MatSelectModule module in imports section.

```
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CreateUserComponent ],
      imports : [ReactiveFormsModule,        
        MatSelectModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,......

      ],
      providers: [.........]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: Many thanks, I add MatCheckboxModule and resolve my problem.

Comment: Instead of importing an entire module, mock the component with [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks)

Answer (score 75):

For anyone experiencing this in **angular 9+**

This issue can also be experienced if you do not declare your component or import the module that declares the component.

Lets consider a situation where you intend to use `ng-select` but you forget to import it Angular will throw the error 'No value accessor...'

I have reproduced this error in the [Below stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uyk7vs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: A better answer would be with a solved demo, instead of recreating the same error

Comment: @Lenzman I think the solution is quite clear. This answer is to assist anyone who might be facing this issue because of not importing a particular component. If you believe this is not a solution you were looking for or expect others to find here on SO, you are welcomed to provide your solution

Comment: @OwenKelvin, the solution is not clear to me. Import exactly what exactly where? Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

If you get this issue, then either

- the formControlName is not located on the value accessor element.
- or you're not importing the module for that element.

Comment: In my case I was missing MyDatePickerModule from imports in my call to TestBed.configureTestingModule

Comment: Missing the import of the module for the element. This helped!

Comment: Or the component doesn't appear in it's own module in declarations & exports

Answer (score 14):

If you must use the label for the `formControl`. Like the Ant Design Checkbox. It may throw this error while running tests. You can use `ngDefaultControl`

```
<label nz-checkbox formControlName="isEnabled" ngDefaultControl>
    Hello
</label>

<nz-switch nzSize="small" formControlName="mandatory" ngDefaultControl></nz-switch>
```

Comment: Update another better way here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73327822/4493738

Answer (score 11):

In some cases you might missed to add `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` in reusable component as provider.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-reusable',
    templateUrl: './reusable.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./reusable.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => ReusableComponent),
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case I was using ionic, I was trying to unit test ion-input with jasmine karma.
I was getting the no value accessor error in the karma browser while running the tests. So I just added the `ngDefaultControl` to the ion-input and it solved the problem.

```
<ion-input class="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" 
                type="password" #pw="ngModel" required ngDefaultControl>
</ion-input>
```

Comment: I have two different projects on the same framework versions, one needed the ngDefaultControl, the other worked fine without it.  Weird.

Comment: I did a refactor and now my ionic form require the ngDefaultControl. Not sure why

Answer (score 7):

OR

You need to move your `formControlName="controlName"` to the `<mat-radio-group>` wrapper instead of binding it to the individual `<mat-radio-button>` element (s)

Answer (score 5):

For me I was using primeng dropdown in angular app.

The module for dropdown was not imported.

Comment: Had the same exact problem. Talk about misleading error messages.

Comment: Thank you so much, couldn't figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I used Angular forms with `contenteditable` elements like `div` and had similar problems before.

I wrote [ng-contenteditable](https://github.com/KostyaTretyak/ng-contenteditable) module to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

You can see formControlName in label , removing this solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

```
    constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    @Optional() 
    @Self() public ngControl: NgControl,
    ) {

    if (ngControl) {
        ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
      }

}
```

In my case, add this line in custom Control (reuseable) component's constructor

```
if (ngControl) {
        ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had the error with ionic date pickers only, I had to import the `IonicModule` to my lazy-loaded module

Comment: For Ionic Users, this is the solution if you're working in a custom component.