# ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'products'

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

my project show this error:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'products'.

I want to add an array Products in Myform component.

I have 2 problems:

1. When I click button Register, I see this error.
2. My products array come in order in the table, but when Register, this array is empty. My source code.

Html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="Myform" (ngSubmit)="onaddMyForm()">
  <div class="contant">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select formControlName="client_id" id="client_id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="client">
          <option value="" disabled selected>ClientName</option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of client" [value]="item.client_id">{{item.clientName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <label for="total">total:</label>
          <input formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <table formControlName="products" align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr style="color:black;">
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantita</th>
        <th>Subtotale</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr [routerLink]="i" class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products; let i=index">
        <td>{{item.Price}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Quantita}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Subtotale}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <div id="add_homebox_button_container" class="row" style="float: right;">
    <button id="add_client_button" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
      Register
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My ts code:

My constructors:

```
     constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private ss: ws,

      ) {
// I create the formGroup
            this.Myform = new FormGroup({
              'client_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
              'products': this.fb.array([]),
              'total': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
            });
            }

//My function that post in ws My form Value
              onaddMyForm() {
            this.loading = true;
            let newprod = new Product(
              this.Myform.value
            );
            console.log(newprod)// in console my array is empty

            this.ss.prodcreate(newprod).subscribe(
              result => {
                if (result === true) {
                  Materialize.toast('Prod saved successfully', 4000);
                     } else {
                  this.loading = false;
                }
              },
              error => {
                this.loading = false;
              }
            );
          }
```

How should I do to fix it?
Img err

[image]

Comment: How can a table be a form control?

Comment: formControlName="products" ??

Comment: The goal of a formControl is to input data if i am not mistaken. So how would you input data using a table? What is your goal in dooing that? You might want to have a look at the [FormControlName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName) directive

Comment: Made sure the quote is shown as a quote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No value accessor for form control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070478/no-value-accessor-for-form-control)

Answer (score 3):

well, i was in a similar issue "ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified "

i tried to solved it for 2 days, searched complete Stackoverflow,

at last what worked and what i did

- look for all the ngModel in your code and add name attribute to it.
- if name is specified add "ngDefaultControl" to it

Comment: Thank you!  this was beating me up.  I was getting the right response in the view, but the console was giving the ugly error message.  Adding ngDefaultControl got rid of the error message.