# How to get the correct form status when using custom input forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I use a custom `input` in a component and add it in parent component. Every things works fine except the `form.status`. I just can't get the correct status to toggle the `button` when Valid/Invalid.

Where is the missing part I should change/fix?

```
`<button mat-raised-button 
         name="buttonName" 
        [disabled]="!form.valid" 
        [color]="'primary'">
 </button>`
```

**`form.component.html`**:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <app-input [parentFormGroup]="form" 
           [label]="'e-mail'" 
           [type]="'text'"
           [name]="'User-Email'"
           [required]="true" 
           [pattern]="(email_regEx)">
    </app-input>
</form>
```

**`input.component.html`**:

```
<input matInput 
       type="{{inputType}}" 
       name="{{inputName}}" 
       [(ngModel)]="model" 
       #ngForm="ngModel" 
       (ngModelChange)="modelChange.next($event)" 
       required="{{required}}" 
       pattern="{{regEx}}" 
       #{{inputName}}
>
```

`<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>` --> totally empty, no field names. Must shows form fields
 `<pre>{{ form.status | json }}</pre>` -- > "VALID" must be "INVALID"

**`input.component.ts`**:

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

    public parentFormGroup: FormGroup;

    @Input('label') inputLabel: string;
    @Input('name') inputName: string;
    @Input('type') inputType: string;
    @Input('pattern') regEx: string;
    @Input() required = true;

    @Input() model: any;
    @Output() modelChange = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed. I did add **`ngDefaultControl`** in the parent component. So to be clear, embedding the custom input in the parent component should be:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <app-input [parentFormGroup]="form" 
           [label]="'e-mail'" 
           [type]="'text'"
           [name]="'User-Email'"
           [required]="true" 
           [pattern]="(email_regEx)"
           ngDefaultControl>
    </app-input>
</form>
```

and the hint was mentioned in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072163/error-error-no-value-accessor-for-form-control-with-name-products):