# How to fix 'Error: No value accessor for form control with name' in Angular Unit Test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-ngmodel

I fail to test a component that uses a custom component with ngModel

HTML code looks like this (see more in the repro below)

```html
<custom-control name="formCode" [(ngModel)]="testValue"></custom-control>
```

The code is working in my app but it fails in my test with the following error

> Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'formCode'
>
> Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'formCode'

The tests are run with jasmine

I tried different imports but none seem to fix my issue

The repro code is here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-test-ng-model

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is because you are mocking your CustomControlComponent in your test. Install @angular/material and its dependencies in your package.json and use the spec file below. The test will pass.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-test-ng-model-vsk5re

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, DefaultValueAccessor, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
// import { MockComponent } from 'ng2-mock-component';
import{MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';

import { ParentControlComponent } from './parent-control';
import {CustomControlComponent} from '../custom-control/custom-control';

describe('ParentControlComponent', () => {
    let component: ParentControlComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentControlComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
              CustomControlComponent,
              ParentControlComponent,
                // MockComponent({ selector: 'custom-control' }),
            ],
            imports: [
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                MatFormFieldModule,
                MatInputModule
            ],
            providers: [
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentControlComponent);

        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know any way to mock the child component ?


I'll open an issue in the github.com/cnunciato/ng-mock-component 


Update : an issue is already opened (https://github.com/cnunciato/ng-mock-component/issues/19)

Answer (score 49):

In my case, I was using a customised Angular Component (SingleSelectModule) that weren't imported in the Unit test file. I hope this could help anybody else that run into the same issue than me:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { CaselistComponent } from './caselist.component';
import { SingleSelectModule } from '@uimf/uitk/components/single-select';

describe('Component: CaselistComponent', () => {
  let component: CaselistComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CaselistComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [
            ...
          ],
          imports: [
            FormsModule,
            SingleSelectModule,
            RouterTestingModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule

          ],
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],

        }).compileComponents();

});

});
```

Comment: ya, its a very misleading error check your `imports` for custom form inputs. thanks for the fix mate

Comment: Searched that error ... came here ... this solved my issue ... opened again to upvote the answer, just to realise I've already upvoted it in the past. That's how bad and misleading this exception is.

Answer (score 2):

You can create mock component without 3rd lib

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';


const mockControlValueAccessor = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useValue: {
    writeValue: () => {},
    registerOnChange: () => {},
    registerOnTouched: () => {}
  },
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-select-control',
  template: '',
  providers: [mockControlValueAccessor]
})
class MockCustomSelectComponent {
  public open(): void {}
  public close(): void {}
}


describe(TestingComponent.name, () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let hostComponent: HostComponent;
  let component: StripePaymentComponent;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
      providers: [],
      declarations: [TestingComponent, MockCustomSelectComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone finds that the other answers did not help, In my case I had to remove from the unit test declarations this:

`ReactiveFormsModule`

after doing that it got rid of the error, but do check if there are any other declarations that are not suppose to be there.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Don't know why however, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix is to use `ngDefaultControl` on the child element tag from the parent's template code.

---

However. Adding ngDefaultControl on the child component tag in the parent html template code is not a good practice when the child component manually implements the ControlValueAccessor. In that case the unit test needs to be adjusted to conform the context.

This is a code snippet that shows how it can be fixed from inside the unit tests' code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bindable-dropdown',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: MockBindableDropdownComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
class MockBindableDropdownComponent extends DefaultValueAccessor {
  config: unknown;
  list: unknown;
  isReadOnly: boolean;
  showError: boolean;
  conditionalCheck: boolean;
}
```

The key part here is `extends DefaultValueAccessor`, which basically, together with the NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR provider, is the equivalent of the 'ngDefaultControl' from the template code.