# Angular unit Test: Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'phoneNumber'

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

In my Angular Component I am using a 3rd party Component that is part of a form, a simplified template would look like this:

```
<form novalidate autofill="off" [formGroup]="addPhoneForm">
    <div>
        <int-phone-prefix [locale]="'en'" [defaultCountry]="'us'" formControlName="phoneNumber"></int-phone-prefix>
     </div>
     <div>
        <input type="text"formControlName="phoneName">
    </div>
</form>
```

Everything works great... until it is time to write tests for my component's methods. I know that I need to mock the 3rd party component to prevent it complaining about the component not being a known element. I also don't want to not use `[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` as the 3rd party component is part of my `FormGroup`. So in my test file I add a mock like so before I set up my test suite, notice how I add a `formControlName` to the mock template, how I add the mock to the `declarations` array and how I even use `forwardRef` in my `providers` array so the mock will be considered part of my form....

```
// Mock Component
@Component({
  template: '<input type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber">',
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  selector: 'int-phone-prefix',
})
class IntPhonePrefixComponent {
  constructor() { }
}

describe('AddPhoneComponent', () => {
  let component: AddPhoneComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddPhoneComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AddPhoneComponent, IntPhonePrefixComponent],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          multi: true,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => IntPhonePrefixComponent),
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

However, despite the mock and including it in my providers array and the declarations array I still get the following error when I run my test suite.

**Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'phoneNumber'**

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the typo (missing ") just in the question or also in the component? `<form novalidate autofill="off [formGroup]="addPhoneForm">`

Comment: Good spot... that is just in the question, I will fix that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `providers` array are in the wrong place: it's the `int-phone-prefix` that should have the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`, not the testing module itself.

The simplest solution would be to stub the three required `ControlValueAccessor` methods for the stub `IntPhonePrefixComponent` (and move the `provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR // etc.` fragment to its decorator). I'm not arguing that it's the best or the most elegant one, probably not.

Comment: Thanks for that, could you expand on your answer with a code example please?

Answer (score 3):

To get the tests working I changed my mock to the following...

```
// Mock Component
@Component({
  template: '<input type="text">',
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  selector: 'int-phone-prefix',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => IntPhonePrefixComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
class IntPhonePrefixComponent {
  constructor() { }
  writeValue(): void {}
  registerOnChange(): void {}
  registerOnTouched(): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ngDefaultControl to int-phone-prefix

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix such failing test would be to implement the NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR provider while also extending from DefaultValueAccessor class. Check out my answer from this other SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741180/5780536