# Angular Unit Test: Error: No value accessor for form control

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, form-control, controlvalueaccessor

I am abstracting each field from my form as follows (this works in development but not in my unit test)

```js
// required.control.ts
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    
    export class RequiredControl extends FormControl {
      protected textErrors: { [key: string]: string } = {
        required: 'Mandatory field'
      };
    
      constructor(value: string | any = '') {
        super(value);
    
        this.setValidators([Validators.required]);
      }
    
      get textError() {
        let message = '';
        for (const error in this.textErrors) {
          if (error && this.hasError(error) && this.dirty) {
            message = this.textErrors[error];
    
            return message;
          }
        }
    
        return message;
      }
    
      get state() {
        return this.valid || !this.dirty ? '' : 'error';
      }
    }
```

This way I can clean up my form and bring the validation logic for each field to a separate file. Now, in the main component I import this file:

```js
// my-component.component.ts
import { RequiredControl } from './required.control.ts';

@Component({})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit { // I skiped import for this OnInit

   reasonControl = new RequiredControl(null);

   constructor() {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.requestForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      reason: this.reasonControl, // first method tried :(
      reason:this.reasonControl as FormControl, // second method tried :(
     });
   }
}
```

In my unit tests I have the following:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, RouterTestingModule] 
    })
}));
```

I have this in my template:

[image]

When I run this test I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the correct solution for my issue, use the `ngDefaultControl` in the input element, like this:

[image]

This attribute gives the necessary knowledge to the test to be able to identify this element as a `FormControl` in third-party components (as is my case). Adding that attribute solves the problem.

Comment: I dont think is the correct way to handle this. If you are using any 3rd party component you should import that as well in your unit test or mock it.

Comment: I tried but it was impossible for me and I have good behavior in my test and the form controls it has the correct values.

Comment: with this solution, you are adding some code which is only to tackle unit test cases which is not right thing to do. If you could create a stackblitz sample may we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `ngDefaultControl` might not be the best option, especially when the child component manually implements the ControlValueAccessor interface.

A better way would be to implement the NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR provider while also extending from DefaultValueAccessor class.

Check out my answer from this other SO thread for an alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741180/5780536