# Cypress component test with ControlValueAccessor fails to find value accessor

Tags: angular, cypress, angular17, cypress-component-testing

I'm trying to write a component test for my component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`. The component itself works without issue, but when I try and test it via cypress, I'm getting the "No value accessor for form control unspecified name attribute" error.

This is how I'm trying to mount the component:

```
const collateralFixture: CollateralByAreaArray[] = [
    {
        'areaName': v4(),
        'collateral': [
            Collateral.forTesting(),
            Collateral.forTesting()
        ]
    },
    {
        'areaName': v4(),
        'collateral': [
            Collateral.forTesting(),
            Collateral.forTesting()
        ]
    }
]

cy
    .mount('<app-collateral-expansion-panel [formControl]="control" />', {
        componentProperties: {
            control: new FormControl<CollateralByAreaArray[]>(collateralFixture)
        },
        imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, IgxExpansionPanelModule ]
    })
```

Since I properly provide the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` in the component, why do I get this error while trying to test?

I'm using version 13.6.6 of cypress and 17.2.4 of Angular.

`Collateral` is just a class object, that has children, and the `forTesting()` method just creates random values for the object.

Comment: Can you be more specific on this line `new FormControl<CollateralByAreaArray[]>(...)`? What do you pass as content for those `...`.

Comment: @Wilt I'm just passing the array object to be displayed.  See updated description. It's a static list of items, not being added/removed, so I don't want the extra overhead of dealing with a FormArray here.

Comment: Is your problem maybe caused by [the same problem like mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242423/1697459)? Also checkout [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75518911/1697459) or one of the other related answers.