# A problem with "No value accessor for form control with name"

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, primeng, form-control

I'm preparing a stackblitz for a problem that I have with child-parent communication, but along the way, I've been confronted with a different issue, namely, I'm getting the following error: `No value accessor for form control with name: 'endDateFC'`. This happens also for `startDateFC`.

I tried the following things from SO:

1. I added `ReactiveFormsModule` and `FormsModule`
2. I removed the duplicates of `FormsModule`. I have the import only in the `app.modules.ts`

According to: [No value accessor for form control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070478/no-value-accessor-for-form-control)

1. I didn't mix label and input. There is no name collision.
2. I have all declarations, imports, etc.
3. `formControlName` is located on the value accessor element

What is wrong with my code?
Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-v-zdd3of?file=src/app/postpone-dialog/postpone-dialog.component.ts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47795277/6468645) and [this one to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46465959/6468645), adding `ngDefaultControl` next to the formcontrol name solves your problem: [stackblitz fixed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-v-kxhsir?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/postpone-dialog/postpone-dialog.component.html)

Answer (score 7):

If you implemented `ControlValueAccessor` but still get the error *"No value accessor for form control with name"*, then **DON'T** add `ngDefaultControl` but instead add the missing provider to your `@Component()`, like so:

```
providers: [
  { 
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    multi: true,
    useExisting: MyComponent,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the possible reasons: in your component you are using `@Input formControl` and it conflicts with `formControl` directive.