# How to use reactive form's formControlName with a custom component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating a simple Reactive form in Angular. There is already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070478/no-value-accessor-for-form-control) question and is marked duplicate.

But mine is different. In my case I've a custom component on which I want to use `formControlName`.
Though the form is working correctly but there is an error on console. Please tell me how to fix this.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="myReactiveform" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <my-file-uploader
    formControlName="attatchmentControl">
  </my-file-uploader>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
myReactiveform: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myReactiveform= new FormGroup({
    attatchmentControl: new FormControl('', [])
  });
  submitForm() {
    ...
  }
}
```

**my-file-uploader.component.html**

```
<input type="file" single>
```

**Error**

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'attatchmentControl'
> at _throwError (forms.js:2574:1)
> at setUpControl (forms.js:2394:1)
> at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5626:1)
> at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6177:1)
> at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6122:1)
> at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1471:1)
> at callHook (core.js:2490:1)
> at callHooks (core.js:2457:1)
> at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2408:1)
> at selectIndexInternal (core.js:8194:1)

Answer (score 1):

Your custom component must implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface

In the `@Component` directive add:

```js
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    multi: true,
    useExisting: MyFileUploaderComponent // your component class name
  }]
```

Then in the component implement the interface (for example):

```js
export class MyFileUploaderComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  control = new FormControl();

  onChange(event) {
    this.onTouched();
  }

  onTouched() {
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.control.setValue(obj);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    if (isDisabled) {
      this.control.disable();
    } else {
      this.control.enable();
    }
  }
}
```

A few more notes:

- you should initialize the form at the class level (when you define variable) or in the constructor, not in `ngOnInit`.
- move `submitForm()` to class level unless that's a typo or bad copy/paste.